# How to prevent flickering in WinForms when quickly updating a value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple Winforms GUI which has a TrackBar in a GroupBox its title I'm using to display the value of the contained TrackBar:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTrackBarPositionText();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTrackBarPositionText();
}

private void UpdateTrackBarPositionText()
{
    groupBox1.Text = ORIGINAL_TRACKBAR_TEXT + qualitySelector.Value.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that when scrubbing over the bar, both it and the label of the group are flickering, especially when scrubbing quickly. Also CPU usage is fairly high for such a simple action. How can I improve this implementation? I want to update the value in real time, not just after letting go, so that the users sees the value while selecting it. `DoubleBuffered = true;` does nothing.

EDIT:
I used reflection at instantiation to set the GroupBox and the bar to double buffered. That helped with the Box, but the slider still flickers :(

Comment: What else have you got going on in the app?  Do you have a bunch of graphics on your form?  Show us a screenshot please.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I ended up creating a user control using a picture box where I filled in partially likea progress bar, but it responded to user clicks and slides.

Comment: There is nothing else in the app. It's literally a GUI that does nothing. Except for the described elements, there are two buttons and one TextBox. Nothing's running in the background

Comment: You need to enable DoubleBuffering for each control that shows flicker. Here it is the GroupBox, so use a subclass: `class DBGroupbox : GroupBox
    {
        public DBGroupbox() { DoubleBuffered = true; ; }
    }` Maybe other controls nested  in the GB  also needt this, if there are any, that is..

Comment: I think you blame WinForms for this one. Certain controls are notorious for flickering. For testing I tried `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer , true);` but it made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Hmm, programmers not understanding double-buffering is a notorious problem.  Not the form, it has to be the GroupBox.  Which does not double-buffer out of the (tool)box, it was meant as a container control with a "label" that normally doesn't get updated at a high rate.

Comment: I used reflection to make the affected items double buffered and it helped partially. The slider still flickers though.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann - Did you try to do the same thing for the slider too?

Comment: Turns out I made a mistake for the slider, now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [Double Buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) set.  If not start there and then other methods as needed.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have it enabled.

Comment: But none of the flickering items have a DoubleBuffered property

Comment: I ended up using reflection to set it for all the flickering components and now it looks great :)

Comment: That's the other option. I usually prefer using a subclass as it invites me to add more behaviour to it.. I had shown it in my other comment! If your really slider still flickers you ought to know now what to do..

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical use case for a timer. Make it update the label at, say, 10 times per second. Any more than that is really an overkill because nobody can read it that fast anyway.

You can have the timer permanently enabled, or (as an optimization) you can enable it at `trackBar1_Scroll` and disable it in the timer itself, if the value hasn't changed for the past few ticks. In fact, if the value hasn't changed since the last update, don't update the label either (might save some extra flickering).

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try. But that sounds like a hack - is this "normal procedure"?

Comment: Yes, a hack and not nomal; normal is doublebuffering the controls that are flickering. Not the form but the GroupBox!

Comment: This doesn't help, it merely ensures that it updates at 10 Hz max.  That's flicker to anybody's eyes.

Comment: It's a normal procedure. Well, it's more common to see this in places where a background process does a lot of processing and the status updates many times each second. For example, consider copying a file. For progress there is a label "bytes copied". The copying process could update this a million times a second to keep it "accurate". But that would just be pointless overhead because nobody can read it a million times per second. Updating the label at 10-20fps is enough to get a fairly smooth progress animation while keeping the overhead negligible.

Comment: Nevertheless, this approach applicable here as well and is simple to implement too.

Answer (score 1):

This does not address this question, but it creates a workaround with a custom control that does the same thing.

[image: pic]

```
public partial class SliderControl : Control
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
    public int MinValue { get; set; } 
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public SliderControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint|ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.MinValue=0;
        this.MaxValue=100;
        this.Value=50;
        this.Text="Value";
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        SetBoundsCore(Left, Top, Width, 32, BoundsSpecified.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Width-1, Height-16);
        using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Value*(Width-1)/MaxValue-1, Height-16);
            gp.AddRectangle(rect);
            using (var br = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.SteelBlue, Color.LightBlue, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
            {
                pe.Graphics.FillPath(br, gp);
                pe.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.DarkBlue, gp);
            }
        }
        var text = $"{this.Text} = {this.Value}";
        var sz = pe.Graphics.MeasureString(text, SystemFonts.SmallCaptionFont);
        pe.Graphics.DrawString(text, SystemFonts.SmallCaptionFont, Brushes.Black, Width/2-sz.Width/2, Height-16);
    }

    private void SetClickValue(Point click_point)
    {
        int x = (click_point.X+1)*MaxValue/Width;
        this.Value=x;
        this.Refresh();
        this.ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);

        if (e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            SetClickValue(e.Location);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            SetClickValue(e.Location);
        }
    }

}
```